# pulling covid deaths from covid19_open_data using bq

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

I am trying to get COVID19 deaths history per country using Google's SDK. I installed bq (BigQuery) on Ubuntu, but I don't know how to proceed. The online API gives some [examples](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=transjapan-1592306300454&folder=&organizationId=&sq=1056986132837:0c435df9e5e145da81c06fa9f33e51fe) but they seem irrelevant. I expect something like `bq extract bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data` but can't find instructions. I feel clueless here, thanks for your help.

Comment: This is probably not programming-focused enough for Stack Overflow, but it looks like you can find the specific datasets at https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?filter=solution-type:dataset&filter=category:covid19 which I found via https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-datasets/covid19-public-data-program .

Comment: thanks. this is how I got there, but I can't get their data, maybe because of a lack of DB experience.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I managed to get the data I wanted with the online API (link above in the question). I used the code below. However, the data was noisy and spiky for Sweden and other countries, similarly to Johns Hopkins data, so I have to keep looking for a more reliable source of data. it seems that [WHO](https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv) has better data

```
WITH
  country_pop AS (
  SELECT
    country_code AS iso_3166_1_alpha_3,
    year_2018 AS population_2018
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_global_population.population_by_country`)
SELECT
  date,
  new_deceased,
  new_intensive_care_patients,
  new_confirmed,
  new_tested
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data`
JOIN
  country_pop
USING
  (iso_3166_1_alpha_3)
WHERE
  country_name = 'Sweden'
  AND aggregation_level = 0
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```